# How to get value of Checkbox and save in Array?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, checkbox

I have a checkbox like this:

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.lyLayout);
CheckBox checkBox;

for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    checkBox = new CheckBox(getBaseContext());
    checkBox.setId(View.generateViewId());
    checkBox.setText(items.get(i).getDesk());
    layout.addView(checkBox); 
}
```

and I want to get checked data, I do this :

```
ArrayList<String> checkedBox = new ArrayList<>();
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
    for (int a = 0; a < layout.getChildCount(); a++) {
        checkBox = (CheckBox) layout.getChildAt(a);
        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            checkedBox.add(checkBox.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), checkedBox.toString() + " checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            checkedBox.remove(checkBox.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), checkedBox.toString() + " checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

but the captured data is only at index 0. Other than that, the data is not stored. And sometimes the data is not stored at all.

Comment: `checkBox` refers to the last check box added only, so you are only registering a listener on the last one.

Comment: thank you, that's helped me.
I finally understand where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following code.

```
 private ArrayList<String> getCheckBoxData(){
     ArrayList<String> checkedBox = new ArrayList<>();
     for (int a = 0; a < layout.getChildCount(); a++) {
         checkBox = (CheckBox) layout.getChildAt(a);
         if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
              checkedBox.add(checkBox.getText().toString());
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), checkBox.getText().toString() + " checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         } 
     }
 return checkedBox;
 }
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question.
I've tried your suggestion, but still can't get the data. I think I was wrong when adapting your code to mine.

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to solve the error

I changed my code from this:

```
ArrayList<String> checkedBox = new ArrayList<>();
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> 
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < layout.getChildCount(); a++) {
        checkBox = (CheckBox) layout.getChildAt(a);
        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
        checkedBox.add(checkBox.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), checkedBox.toString() + " checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            checkedBox.remove(checkBox.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), checkedBox.toString() + " checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

to this :

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
                                        if(isChecked){
                                            checkedBox.add(buttonView.getText().toString());
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), checkedBox.toString() + " checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        } else {
                                            checkedBox.remove(buttonView.getText().toString());
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), checkedBox.toString() + " checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    });
```